# fractal curve / levy curve issues

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

I am having issues with a fractal curve. I have tried this both on Python 2.7 and 3.6 on OS X El Capitan. I cannot get the turtle to move. This is the code taken directly from the book. [screenshot of turtle not moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV3mv.png) With it set to 0, it should, according to the book, draw a straight line. But it does not move. The book gives us the code:

```
from turtle import Turtle

def cCurve(t, x1, y1, x2, y2, level):
    def drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2):
        t.up()
        t.goto(x1, y1)
        t.down()
        t.goto(x2, y2)

        if level == 0:
            drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        else:
            xm = (x1 + x2 + y1 - y2) //2
            ym = (x2 + y1 + y2 - x1) //2
            cCurve(t, x1 ,y1 ,xm, ym, level -1)
            cCurve(t, xm, ym, x2, y2, level -1)
def main():
    level = int(input("Enter the level(0 or greater):" ))
    t = Turtle()
    t.hideturtle()
    cCurve(t, 50, -50, 50, 50, level)


main()
```

Comment: The indentation is wrong at `if level == 0` and further;

Comment: The `drawLine()` function whose definition is nested inside the `cCurve()` function is never called—so nothing ever gets drawn.

Comment: The book states that this program includes 3 function definitions cCurve, drawLine, and main. Because the drawLine is an auxiliary function, its definition is nested within the cCurve.  Which is why it is nested.

Comment: @ trincot  Thank you. You helped me solve my problem of why it would not move.

Answer (score 0):

After addressing the indentation issue that @trincot points out, I wanted to demonstrate that folks, and books, often miss the value of turtle's `Vec2D` class when writing programs like this.  Although `Vec2D` isn't perfect, lacking a nice way to access invidual elements and no division, so you have to use multiplicaion, it can clean up code by dealing with points instead of individual X and Y values:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D

X, Y = range(2)

def cCurve(turtle, p1, p2, level):

    def drawLine(turtle, p1, p2):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(p1)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.goto(p2)

    if level == 0:
        drawLine(turtle, p1, p2)
    else:
        s = (p1 + p2) * 0.5  # sum / 2
        d = (p1 - p2) * 0.5  # difference / 2

        m = Vec2D(s[X] + d[Y], s[Y] - d[X])

        cCurve(turtle, p1, m, level - 1)
        cCurve(turtle, m, p2, level - 1)

def main():
    level = int(input("Enter the level (0 or greater): "))

    screen = Screen()

    cCurve(Turtle(visible=False), Vec2D(50, -50), Vec2D(50, 50), level)

    screen.mainloop()

main()
```

[image]

And you can import `Vec2D` into programs that don't have *anything* to do with turtles.